# Angular não reconhece componente

Tags: angular

O Angular não reconhece um componente no meu projeto, mesmo estando tudo correto, segue o código:

Este é o header.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.scss'
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

Este é o home.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent {

}
```

Este é o app.routes.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
    //Components
    import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
    
    //Page
    import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [HomeComponent, HeaderComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ]
    })
    export class HomeModule { }

Este é o app.routes.ts:

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './modules/home/pages/home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [{path: '', component: HomeComponent}];
```

eu uso o header dentro do home component usando a tag:

```
<app-header><app-header/>
```

porem o angular nn reconhece, este é o erro:

```
NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
src/app/modules/home/pages/home/home.component.html:2:0
```

Eu havia formatado o meu pc pois achei que podia ser algum problema na versão ou nos arquivos do angular e o unico comando que usei antes da criação do projeto para instalar o angular foi: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
e logo apos ja usei `ng new` então talvez tenha faltado instalar algo que nn sei. mas no geral o home.component aparece na pagina principal entao esta tudo certo com o routes, o unico erro é realmente no uso do header dentro do home component.

Comment: Pode ser várias coisas e pelo post não temos como saber, uma das coisas que pode ser, é que se vc criou o `header.component` em um módulo, vc terá que importar este módulo no **imports**  no `home.module`.

Comment: no caso eu tenho uma pasta modules dentro da pasta app, na pasta modules eu tenho um modulo home e na pasta do module home eu tenho mais duas pastas, uma chamada components e uma chamada pages, o componente header esta na pasta components e o component home esta na pasta pages, ambos os componentes são importados dentro do modulo home e o componente heder deve ser chamado dentro do componente home.

Comment: se vc pudesse me dar um exemplo eu agradeceria muito pq eu ja procurei em todo lugar e nn sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: tenta remover o   standalone: true,

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, se você tem dois componentes `standalone: true`, no seu caso você quer usar `app-header` dentro de `app-home`, você precisa importar os componentes que você quer usar no `app-home`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, HeaderComponent],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent {

}
```

Outro ponto importante é que você **não precisa** criar esse module porque é exatamente essa a ideia que o standalone abandona.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).